# Dúvida sobre um construtor do FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

O FragmentStateAdapter possui três construtores conforme a documentação.

> (@NonNull fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity)
>
> (@NonNull fragment: Fragment)
>
> (@NonNull fragmentManager: FragmentManager,@NonNull lifecycle:
>   Lifecycle)

Na minha classe eu estou utilizando o primeiro, dessa forma:

```
class PagerAdapter(val fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

...

}
```

E instancio dessa forma no MainActivity:

```
pager.adapter = PagerAdapter(this@MainActivity)
```

O this@MainActivity que é um AppCompatActivity é passado como parâmetro, o android studio não aponta como erro e o app funciona normalmente.

A dúvida é o meu MainActivity não devia ser um FragmentActivity? Existem cenários que eu posso ter algum tipo de problema com esse tipo de implementação? Lembrando que eu não utilizo a variável fragmentActivity dentro de nenhum método do PagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, beleza?

Cara o AppCompatActivity estende de FragmentActivity.

por isso o Android Studio não aponta como erro, e seu app funciona normalmente.